# Resolve types in Designtime in custom markupextension

Tags: wpf, designer, service-provider, markup-extensions

I have the following problem:

**If I do:** `MyExtension : StaticExtension`,
`ProvideValue` is not always called by the VS2015 designer. When it is called I can do:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var typeResolver = 
        (IXamlTypeResolver)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver));
```

... and resolve the types I need.

**If I do:** `MyExtension : MarkupExtension`, it looks like `ProvideValue` is called the way I need but `serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver));` returns `null`.

Is there a better way?